# RESTful endpoints with different permissions

Tags: rest, api

I'm creating an API where based on the permissions that authenticated user different properties of objects can be changed.

Whats the common way to approach this problem?

Should i have endpoints like

`/admin/users` and `/users` with different API definition and capabilities?

It sounds rather inflexible design, what about situation where user can have permission like `can_modify_foo_prop` and `can_modify_bar_prop`?

I was thinking a better solution would be instead to just provide one endpoint `/users` and based on authenticated user roles some fields would be read-only/hidden instead? That seems more flexible but could be more annoying to document/implement.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, URI means Uniform **Resource Identifier**. Which means a given user (concept) should be always identified by the same URI, hence I would suggest your second proposal, to have a single hierarchy/list of users:

```
/users/1
/users/2
...
```

It is acceptable to define (in the appropriate Media-Type) the returning document to hold properties based on the current user's permissions.

Now, regarding whether that is easy to use or not is subjective. I would argue that returning pure data is *always* somewhat inconvenient, because the client has to parse and understand the data. This is why HTML and HTML Forms were created, so the client does not need to know *how* to present the data, and also doesn't need to know what's editable and what is not. Then again, I don't know your exact use-case.

Comment: Hi, @robert-bräutigam How would you go about handling a situation where the [response and permission are tied to where the API is accessed from ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77612058/best-way-to-identify-user-roles-in-an-api)