# Best way to identify user roles in an api

Tags: rest, http, api-design

I am currently building an API in which users can access resources including theirs publicly, as well as manage it in a dashboard.

In the spirit of having a single resource endpoint to prevent code duplication, how can I identify a logged user on my APIs as accessing his resources from the dashboard or publicly?

Or is this a case where I have no other choice but to build separate endpoints for management and public use?

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the user roles or privileges to the JWT token and checking them in the Rest methods before executing them.

For the Spring Boot Rest implementation for example:

@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('SYSTEM_ADMIN','CUSTOMER_ADMIN')")
@GetMapping("/{customerId}")

If the token has not SYSTEM_ADMIN or CUSTOMER_ADMIN roles, it produces an error.

Comment: This is possible, however, the issue I am having is that the same user can access resources including theirs publicly, and in their dashboard. Both do not require the same fields in their response and do not require the same permission.

So how do I cater for the same user when accessing resources, publicly or privately (dashboard).

Comment: I initially thought of adding a GET parameter to trigger showing some fields and enforce permission whenever that parameter is passed. 

However, it overly complicates the code, and I am quite apprehensive about having a GET parameter trigger different levels of security checks. 

As of the moment, I am leaning towards having different API endpoints despite the risk of code duplications.